# How to make this regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to make regexp (js) for this strings?
**(from 1 to 6 digits) 3 digits 3 digits

(from 1 to 6 digits) from 1 to 4 digits**

**example:**

```
(1) 234 567
(12) 345 678
(123) 456 789
(1234) 567 890
(12345) 678 901
(123456) 789 012
(1) 23
(1) 234
(1) 2345
```

i tried to use this regexp `^(?([1-9]{1,6}))?[ ]?([1-9]{1,3})[ ]?([1-9]{1,3})$` but it doesn't work

Comment: Show us what you tried already?

Comment: ^\(?([1-9]{1,6})\)?[ ]?([1-9]{1,3})[ ]?([1-9]{1,3})$

Comment: With which part are you having trouble?

Comment: @SergeyKutylev: in this case, you should edit your question to add this attempts.

Comment: with (123456) 789 012 and (123456) 78

Comment: Sergey, welcome to the site!  Please check out the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for tips on asking questions that will attract quality answers.  As folks have noted, a question that shows what you've tried already will be more likely to receive an answer.  Thanks for posting that in the comment - please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35203156/edit) your answer to include the regex, in backticks (`).  Thanks!

Comment: @SergeyKutylev: Why did you use `[1-9]` instead of `[0-9]`, is there a reason?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are trying to accomplish or which part is confusing you.  For instance, what is the point of the `(?` at the beginning?  Is that intended to make the opening parenthesis optional?  Because, if so, you didn't mention that in your rules for how you wanted it to work.  So I don't know which part you are wrong on.  Is your description of the rules wrong, or is there some other thing you were trying to accomplish by putting `(?` in the pattern?

Comment: By the way, when a regex pattern "doesn't work", the best course of action is to use an online tester like [regex101](https://regex101.com/#javascript) to play with it until you figure it out.  With an online tester, you can just try each of the smaller parts of the pattern individually until you figure out which part is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This works for what you want:

```
/^\(\d{1,6}\) (\d{3} \d{3}|\d{1,4})$/gm
```

It matches `(`, then one to six digits, then `)`, then '3 digits, a , then three more digits OR one to four digits'

Modes used are `g`(global search) and `m`(multi-line search).

**<kbd>[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vB4iT1/1)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

The below regex will match all your examples.

```
^\(\d{1,6}\)\s+(\d{3}\s+\d{3}|\d{1,4})$
```

In this regular expression "(" are escaped by backslash, \s+ is added between digits as if there is more space between parenthesis and digit it will still match.